# Capturing keys in Hyper-V's Virtual Machine Connection with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to write a script that will also fire when Hyper-V's Machine Connection window is up.

However, that window eats up keyboard events regardless of whether it is maximized or not. I also tried to reload the script when the virtual machine window gets focus, but that did not help either (I read it may help with RDP).

Any way to force the virtual machine connection Window to work with Autohotkey?

Comment: Try running your script with admin privileges.

Comment: Thanks FN. No cigar - keys are still not captured.

Comment: Might just need to intercept the keys at an even lower level. This is more than likely overkill, but it doesn't really get any lower level than this; using [AHI](https://github.com/evilC/AutoHotInterception) (a C#-AHK wrapper for [Interception](http://www.oblita.com/interception)). I don't know how experienced you are, but if you're at least decently experienced, it shouldn't be too hard to set up a script with that sweet wrapper. So maybe it's ok that it's overkill. At least there's basically no doubt it'll work if done right.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Yeah, this is indeed way way way overkill for what I want. (But I believe it will work)